Overloading operators and theorems over isomorphic datatypes in Isabelle
I want to represent durations in Isabelle and exploit type safety. Naturally, I do:
datatype seconds = Seconds (secs: nat)
datatype minutes = Minutes (mins: nat)

That way, the type system will warn me if I try to add to seconds to minutes. The trouble is that I now have to redefine every arithmetic operator/theorems for seconds and minutes, eventhough they are just the same as nat.
Is there a way for me to inherit all (or most of) the terms and theorems concerning nat for the seconds and minutes types? In my head, all I would need to provide is a pair of function f :: seconds => nat, finv :: nat => seconds and g :: minutes => nat and ginv :: nat => minutes and prove that X and Xinv are inverses of each other to guarantee that the two objects are isomorphic, and I should be able to inherit everything.
For example, this should work out of the box
lemma "Seconds 1 + Seconds 2 + Seconds 3 = Seconds 6"
  by auto

I suspect the lifting package is what I'm after, but I'm having trouble (1) being sure it's what I want (2) finding examples on how to use it for this purpose.

This can indeed be done using the lifting package (and type classes).
Represent seconds by naturals
First, we'll tell Isabelle that we want to represent seconds by the set of (all) natural numbers UNIV::nat set:
typedef seconds = ‹UNIV::nat set› ..

The .. applies the default proof method—a proof is needed here because HOL types ought not be empty; so we need the fact that UNIV is nonempty.
Implicitly, typedef registers trivial translation functions Abs_seconds :: nat ⇒ seconds and Rep_seconds :: seconds ⇒ nat with the meaning you have suggested. (For more on the typedef mechanics, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034603/5158425.)
If we want to have nice names for the translation functions, matching those of the datatype in the question, we can define them:
abbreviation ‹Seconds ≡ Abs_seconds›
abbreviation ‹secs ≡ Rep_seconds›

Set up lifting
The typedef statement also implicitly introduced the fact type_definition_seconds that the two translation functions represent a type derived from the set of natural numbers.
HOL.Lifting can use this fact to register a convenient translation between nat and seconds:
setup_lifting type_definition_seconds

Moreover, we will instantiate seconds to the type class plus, enabling the operator + to be used. This requires us to define a plus_seconds operator. For this we will employ lift_definition from the package:
instantiation seconds :: plus
begin
  lift_definition plus_seconds :: ‹seconds ⇒ seconds ⇒ seconds›
    is ‹(+) :: nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat› .
  instance ..
end

lift_definition ... is ... prepends and appends conversions to and from the representation type nat to use nat's plus in the expected manner. More importantly, it sets up transfer rules that can be used in later proofs.
At the end of the lift_definition line, . indicates that there is a trivial proof that the lifted + from nat stays within the type invariant of seconds. (UNIV translates to the trivial invariant True...)
The instance .. proof line is necessary to prove that plus_seconds obeys the axioms of type class plus (which is trivial, for there are none).
Making calculations on seconds work
The question was how to make calculations on seconds work “out of the box.” Thanks to the preceding gymnastics, we can do this easily, if we interject an invocation of the transfer proof method:
lemma ‹Seconds 1 + Seconds 2 + Seconds 3 = Seconds 6›
  (* goal: (Seconds 1::seconds) + Seconds 2 + Seconds 3 = Seconds 6 *)
  apply transfer
  (* goal: (1::nat) + 2 + 3 = 6 *)
  by auto 

Connecting directly to class axioms
By instantiating seconds to richer type classes, we can also inherit a lot of facts more directly. For instance, we could inherit that nat forms a commutative monoid with subtraction (capped at 0) as follows:
instantiation seconds :: comm_monoid_diff
begin
  lift_definition zero_seconds :: ‹seconds› is ‹0::nat› .
  lift_definition minus_seconds :: ‹seconds ⇒ seconds ⇒ seconds›
    is ‹(-) :: nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat› .
  instance by (standard) (transfer, simp)+
end

lemma ‹(s::seconds) + 0 + s - s = s›
  by simp

Again, the boilerplate in the definition is mostly about referring to  the right existing functions on nat. The instance proof is a little harder as comm_monoid_diff has several axioms (that can each be transferred from nat by (transfer, simp)).
The upside of situations where type classes do the job is that you have zero transfer boilerplate in the proofs.
Less boilerplate?
The direct usage of Lifting, I've discussed here, still involves some boilerplate, to transfer definitions and facts.
Isabelle/HOL is quite vast. So there might be approaches with even less boilerplate. On the other hand, looking at transfer lists in HOL-Library such as the one in https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Library/FSet.html, I assume that there is none—or that a more automatic transfer would open up other difficulties. So, I fear that you'll have to add some boilerplate to inherit the definitions and facts that you are interested in. But thanks to the Lifting theory, it should be straightforward.
